# Is there any way to associate the output of uicontrol callback function to its own 'userdata'?

Tags: matlab, callback, uicontrol

For example, my pushbutton uicontrol calls a callback function, 'fun1_callback':

`fh = figure;
    uicontrol(fh,'style','pushbutton','userdata',_______,'callback',@fun1_callback);`

The callback function is in a separate .m file. It returns an output variable, 'out':

`function out = fun1_callback(hobj,callbackdata)
    out = rand(5);
 end`

Is there any to directly return 'out' to the pushbutton's 'userdata' property(where the underscore represents)?

Comment: please show us some example code of what you're doing if you want some efficient help. In the meantime you can also look at the [`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a call to `set` in your callback function

```
function out = fun1_callback(hobj,evt)
   out = rand(5)
   set( hobj , 'UserData' , out )
end
```

After that the result of `out` will be available in the `userdata` of the button.

But if you plan to access these userdata, you will need the handle of the pushbutton to retrieve this data. So I recommend you define your button as :

```
btnHandle = uicontrol(fh,'style','pushbutton','userdata',[],'callback',@fun1_callback);
```

Then to retrieve your `userdata` after they are defined, you can use:

```
myValues = get(btnHandle,'UserData') ;
```

Comment: @HokiThank you Hoki. Is there any difference between using set( hobj , 'UserData' , out ) and setappdata( hobj , 'UserData' , out ) in the callback function? I guess if using setappdata, 'out' is not stored in pushbutton's userdata property, and variable name used in 'setappdata' can be anything instead of 'userdata'?

Comment: @sgyf. Yes, `appdata` are a bit more flexible than `userdata` (which are a remnant of the past). They can be named, you can define as many as you want (more than the number of uicontrol you have on the figure if necessary), and best of all, to call them you only need to provide the handle of _any_ of the control of the figure (the function will work out the `parent` figure by itself).